# PhoneGap WP8 Getpicture imageURI doesn't work when HTML5 page on Web side

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have odd problem, I can't get any answer when I search anywhere.
I develop Windows Phone 8 with phonegap-2.9.0 , 
Here is my code:

```
    navigator.camera.getPicture(picSuccess, picFail, {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
    });

function picSuccess(imageURI) {
    var image = document.getElementById('upimage');
    alert(imageURI);
    image.src = imageURI;
    $('#camera_status').html("OK");
}

function picFail(message) {
    //alert('Failed because: ' + message);
    $('#camera_status').html("error" + message);
}
```

In HTML5, I also have

after getPicture, It was success and alert show: **///CapturedImagesCache/wp_20131205_001.jpg**
`$('#camera_status').html("OK")`; <------ this one also show no problem.

but `<img>` tag always doesn't show picture on screen!!!!!!

I think problem with where is HTML page,I put HTML5 page in local,It is work,but when I put HTML5 page on my server that it doesn't work, because img src="///capturedImagescache/wp_20131205_001.jpg" not in my web server.

Anyone can help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: after success, the img should be <img id="upimage" width=150 src="///CapturedImagesCache/wp_20131205_001.jpg "/>
why it doesn't show??

Comment: If HTML5 page put on Server side,It doesn't work,How can I do?

Comment: R u able to see dat image in gallery ??

Comment: I think problem with where is HTML page,I put HTML5 page in local,It work ok,but when I put HTML5 page on my server that it doesn't work,
because when <img sr="///capturedImagescache/wp_20131205_001.jpg"> 
not in my web server. So how can I do ?

Comment: it will tak server path and as dat image does not exist out der u wont be able to c... To fix this u need to have dat image on server

Comment: but I just want user pick picture from their phone and my page must put on my server (user ASP.NET). So when local load phonegap page from server then select gallery, will return ///captureXXXXXX, I have to convert to real storage path of uri, and show it and upload it.
but .... how to do?